# Is there a way to perform nested filtering in elastic without affecting whether or not a document is a match?

Tags: elasticsearch

My search document represents a product and inside it I have a `[Nested]` list of SKUs.

What I realized today, is that documents aren't returned if there are no SKUs that match the nested query. I was incorrectly under the impression that my nested query would not affect whether or not a document is returned, but only affect the nested items that I query against.

Is there a way, in elastic, to return documents if they match my top level query and only have the nested query affect the items in the nested list?

I am of course not attached to the nested type, if there is a different way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

An example query is as follows:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 24,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "lang": {
                            "value": "en"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "launchDateTime": {
                            "lte": "2019-11-21T00:00:00-06:00",
                            "relation": "within"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "sKUs.visibilityStartDateTime": {
                                    "lte": "2019-11-21T00:00:00-06:00",
                                    "relation": "within"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "sKUs",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "sKUs.visibilityEndDateTime": {
                                    "gt": "2019-11-21T00:00:00-06:00",
                                    "relation": "within"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "sKUs",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {...}
}
```

Essentially, I still want a product to be returned even if there aren't any visible SKUs. Is there a way to accomplish this while also filtering which SKUs get returned?

**Edit:** 
The partial mapping is as follows:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "productsearchdocument": {
      "properties": {
        ...
        "sKUs": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            ...
            "visibilityStartDateTime": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "visibilityEndDateTime": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            ...
          }
        },
        ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you pleas post the mapping of your index?

Comment: @DanielSchneiter Sorry about that, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use a "Should" filter so that my top level documents are still returned regardless of whether or not my nested query matched anything. The only issue with this would be that it affects the score, which wasn't desired. However, we have an internal scoring system that is used in every situation except text search.